# Using delete function to delete map entry when using http

Tags: http, dictionary, go

I need to delete an entry in a map.
I try to use the "delete" command:

```
var actionResponseChannels = map[string]chan structs.ActionResponse{}
...
delete(actionResponseChannels, refID)
```

but I get an error from go:

> cannot use actionResponseChannels (type map[string]chan
> structs.ActionResponse) as type http.ResponseWriter in argument to
> delete:   map[string]chan structs.ActionResponse does not implement
> http.ResponseWriter (missing Header method)go cannot use refID (type
> string) as type *http.Request in argument to deletego

It seems to me that delete is not related to map functions.

I'm using GO Version 1.13.8 Linux/amd64.

Is there a way to handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: You probably have a `delete` function in your package. Name it something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some HTTP handler function named `delete` in your package that shadows the built-in function. Rename the HTTP handler function.